Producing hedge ratios via regression via returns and not price
I'm a quant student and I need someone to clearly and plainly explain to me better than my professor did about this topic. Please be patient if my question seems very basic.
to find hedge ratios or betas, we typically use linear regression / OLS. However, to get the data, say SPY vs QQQQ, why is it that we want to sample changes over x horizon or returns versus just simply regress price? For example, one data point would be (if sampling period is every 5min), 5 ticks changed over the last 5min versus just taking the price at every 5min?
If we want to say, use QQQQ and regression to imply what SPY price is, would then we use price be ok?
last, why is the fact that we only use the beta and disregard the constant coefficient when constructing the hedge?
Thank you

Not sure if this answers directly to your question, but it might be helpful https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16481/why-do-we-usually-model-returns-and-not-prices

This does shed some more color, thanks for the link. I think (and pls correct me if I'm wrong) is that the discussion there is basically stationarity vs non, and measuring returns whether is just change over some horizon or percent change if it's log, puts assets to compare on the same plane. Once they are on the same plane (as mentioned in the link, like vs like), then we can regress them to produce a coefficient that would minimize the change between the assets and therefore we can get our hedge ratio.

You can ask your additional queries directly in that post.

If you regressed returns of two assets against each other and produced a linear model, the model is basically saying that for a certain return observed for asset X, on average, you would observe a certain return for asset Y. The beta or "hedge ratio" you describe would be a way to "equalize" the returns of both assets.
For example, if asset X is much less volatile than asset Y, a possible linear model you could obtain from regressing returns of Y on X would be Ret_Y = 1.5*Ret_X + C. Therefore, to hedge asset Y, one would need to purchase more of asset X to offset the returns from asset Y, which makes sense.
If you used prices in the regression, you could get a linkage between the prices, but I don't quite see how you could use it to effectively implement a hedge.

Thank you for your answer, and it intuitively makes sense to measure two assets (however different they are) via change vs. change, or returns. Do we simply just discard the constant from the model as a way of saying that's errors or unexplained part and just use the beta coefficient?
Also, as mentioned above sort of a related question. If we were to take asset x and use regression to imply a fair value for asset y, then would using price be ok?

If the residuals are homoscedastic, then it would be okay. If they are heteroskedastic, there are methods meant for that to treat the errors, such as the nonlinear OLS/Kalman filtration methodology for option pricing model calibration. On the price regression, I am honestly not sure, because I haven't worked much with them.

Hi, if you feel my response has helped you, you can give an upvote (if you haven't done so) or accept it as the solution (if it answered your question). :)

This is not an answer but I needed space.
This hedge ratio question is intimately connected to pairs trading. I wouldn't do it justice ( it's quite a large topic with quite a few technical details ) so I'll leave it to this undergrad honors thesis at the  link below. It gives a very nice explanation of the statistical issues when one is trying to compute hedge ratios.  Method 3 starts in Section 3.4  and uses logs of prices. This model  is closest to the model you described but obviously not the same.
Note that using returns ( rather than log prices ) in the regression model is not a good idea because returns tend to be I(0). In the Engle Granger  cointegration setting, the regression variables need to be I(1) and logs of prices meet that criteria.
https://ses.library.usyd.edu.au/bitstream/handle/2123/4072/Thesis_Schmidt.pdf?sequence=1
ADDENDUM: 06-14-2024
I just wanted to add that, in above, one might argue that prices are I(1) so we can use them also. I thought about this recently and it's not a good idea ( atleast as far as I can tell. I welcome corrections ) because if you regress $y$ prices against $x$ prices, then the ratio being estimated is $\hat{\beta_{1}} =\frac{p_{y}}{p_{x}}$. So, $\hat{\beta_{1}}$ represents how many cents y is expected to change for every say 100 cent increase in the price of $x$. But a hedge ratio that is a function of cents ( or any units for that matter ) is not helpful because this in turn implies that the magnitudes of each of the prices matter. One definitely seeks a hedge ratio that is independent of the magnitudes of the prices of the things being regressed and log prices achieve this. This is because when log prices are regressed, the beta estimate becomes $ \hat{\beta_{2}} = \frac{log_{y}}{log_{x}}$ and represents an estimate of: "how much log(y) of $y$ is obtained for every unit percent increase in the log(x) of $x$. But notice that "log(y) of $y$" is the return of $y$ and "$log(x)$ of $x$" is the return of $x$. This is the advantage of using log price rather than price. By using log prices, the $\beta$ relation is a return relation rather than a price relation.
